# parse xml using simplexml_load_file with tag <g:name>

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

i am trying to parse an xml file that has in some of the field names a "g:"

here is a sample of the xml

```
<entry>
       <title><![CDATA[here is the title]]></title>
       <link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com]]></link>
       <g:id><![CDATA[10]]></g:id>
       <g:condition><![CDATA[new]]></g:condition>
 </entry>
```

all i want to do is echo the name and data like this

```
 title: here is the title
 link: http://www.example.com
 id: 10
 condition: new
```

my code is very simple

```
<?php
     $xml=simplexml_load_file("GoogleBaseFeed-2013-10-11.xml");
         foreach($xml->children() as $child)
         {
       foreach($child->children() as $child1)
     {
       echo $child1->getName() . ": " . $child1 . "<br>";
     }
         }
 ?>
```

but this code only echos title and link. it doesn't echo the nodes that start with "g:"

Comment: i see i need to somehow reference the g namespace using     `http://base.google.com/ns/1.0` but i dont know what to do with it.

Comment: @CBore my xml has both tags with a namespace and tags without